# How to execute a VBO using Drush

Tags: 7, views, drush, workflows

So I want to execute a VBO using drush, taking advantage of `vbo-execute` command to change my workflow state in my views, based on few resources I found this is the command I'm using:

```
drush vbo-execute list_of_node_for_expire  action::workflow_vbo_given_state_action argument:1
```

and I end up with this error:

> in field_sql_storage_field_storage_write() (line 514 of
>   /modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module).
>   PDOException:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048
>   Column 'field_workflow_states_value' cannot be null: INSERT
>   INTO {field_data_field_workflow_states} (entity_type, entity_id,
>   revision_id, bundle, delta, language, field_workflow_states_value)
>
> VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_6); Array (
>       [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => node
>       [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 34924
>       [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 34924
>       [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => listing
>       [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0
>       [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => und
>       [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => )

I have no idea why it's giving me such an error, I'm not even sure if it has something to do with VBO or not, but using Views UI, I can execute my VBO with no errors.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of the error, it looks like vbo operation or the action is trying to insert a blank value into the `field_data_field_workflow_states` table.

Without actually seeing any code it's a little harder to determine what's going on in the vbo or the action, but check either `list_of_node_for_expire` or `action::workflow_vbo_given_state_action` and make sure you're working with the correct data before it makes the database request.

Comment: the data and the action seems to be fine, I don't know why it still throws the error